# Is there a way to, for each element, aggregate the maximum value in it's row without that specific element?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensor

I'm wondering whether there is a clever way to express this operation in terms of pure tensor transformations:

[equation](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?X(i,&space;j)&space;=&space;%5Cmax_%7Bj%27&space;%5Cneq&space;&space;j%7DM(i,&space;j%27))

Basically to have each element of a row represent the maximum value in that row without the element.

```py
# Input
[
  [8, -2, 9],
  [7, 100, -2],
  [5, 11, 2]
]

# Result
[
  [9, 9, 8],
  [100, 7, 100],
  [11, 5, 11]
]
```

I can imagine it as **maybe** constructing a matrix like:

```py
[
  [[-2, 9],   [8, 9],  [8, -2]],
  [[100, -2], [7, -2], [7, 100]],
  [[11, 2],   [5, 2],  [5, 11]]
]
```

but I don't know how to go about it.

I'd like it to run solely on the GPU, using the computation graph.

Answer (score -1):

You can use
[`tf.math.top_k`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/top_k)
as follows

```py
x = tf.constant([
  [8, -2, 9],
  [7, 100, -2],
  [5, 11, 2]
])

# Find top 2 values and their indices 
top_pairs_values, top_pair_indices = tf.math.top_k(input=x, k=2)

# True value corresponds to the situation when we need second top value
# False value corresponds to the first top value
condition = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(tf.shape(x)[1]), 0) == top_pair_indices[:, :1]

# We select either top or second top value form top_pairs_values according to the condition
output = tf.where(
    condition=condition, 
    x=top_pairs_values[:, 1:], 
    y=top_pairs_values[:, :1]
)

output
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
# array([[  9,   9,   8],
#        [100,   7, 100],
#        [ 11,   5,  11]], dtype=int32)>
```